# Java I/O: Setting time stamp

Tags: java, io, file-attributes

I'm reading Oracle documentation and encountered something that looks like an error to me.

Perhaps someone can confirm, or explain it better than the documentation.

Source:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html

Code:

```
Path file = ...;
BasicFileAttributes attr =
    Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
FileTime ft = FileTime.fromMillis(currentTime);
Files.setLastModifiedTime(file, ft);
```

Should not `setLastModifiedTime()` be called on `attr` instead of `Files`? (`attr.setLastModifiedTime(file, ft)`)

If not, why is `attr` needed at all?

Comment: `Files` is the class that reads the attributes, so it should also be the one that writes them. It's just a convenient way to do common file operations without interacting with the attributes. `attr` (and indeed its class `BasicFileAttributes`) doesn't seem to be needed in this context, but can be useful because it provides a platform-agnostic way of grouping file properties together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `attr` is unused in this specific snippet, it seems as a copy paste of same code for different snippets,

Because the context of snippets is `Basic File Attributes`

Before and after the sample, other snippets use `attr`, as:

> ```
> System.out.println("size: " + attr.size());  
>
> System.out.println("isReadOnly is " + attr.isReadOnly());
> ```

So in this snippet you can remove unused assignment line

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);`
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I wasn't sure if I had missed some aspect of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The internal code for this method is :

```
  public static Path setLastModifiedTime(Path path, FileTime time)
        throws IOException
    {
        getFileAttributeView(path, BasicFileAttributeView.class)
            .setTimes(time, null, null);
        return path;
    }
```

As you can see it fetches the attribute using getFileAttributeView() and then set the Time on that.

This method is just a convenience API provided in the Files class.

Answer (score 0):

BasicFileAttributes is for getting the basic attributes for many filesystem and it doesn't defined any modification methods. So to modify the `LastModifiedTime` you have to use the method which is defined in the Files class.

FYI: [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setLastModifiedTime(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime))